# Как в слове найти слово

Tags: java

У меня есть список слов ("House", "Mouse", "Bread") и есть слово ("Houses"), как это слово проверить на наличие слова из списка

```
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("House", "Mouse", "Bread");
        if(list.contains("Houses")) {
            System.out.println("Слово Houses содержит House!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Слово Houses не содержит House!");
        }
    }
```

Пытаюсь проверить, но всегда выводит "Слово Houses не содержит House!".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("House", "Mouse", "Bread");
String word = "Houses";
boolean found = false;
for (String item : list) {
  if (word.contains(item)) {
    System.out.println("Слово " + word + " содержит " + item + "!");
    found = true;
  }
}
if (!found) {
  System.out.println("Слово Houses не содержит ни одного элемента списка.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("House", "List", "Something");
    String wordForCheck = "Houses";

    list.forEach(s -> {
        if(wordForCheck.matches(s+"\\w+")){
            System.out.println("HAS");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("HASNT");
        }
    });
```

Можно использовать регулярное выражение:)